# Monodroid. Xamarin. How do I make streaming mp3 playback in Xamarin Studio for Android?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have searched for a while, and never came to a good tutorial showing how to implement this audio streaming feature. There are some Java tutorials out there, but I have struggle understanding those. Does anybody know of a good tutorial on the topic for c sharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, which turned out to be really simple

```
string url = "...";
player.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.Music);
player.SetDataSource(url);
player.Prepare();
player.Start();
```